# Gettig CertificateException: "No name matching localhost found" in Playframework java application

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, playframework, certificate

I have 2 applications, one app is in `Spring Boot` and other is in `Playframework`. I am trying to consume `REST` endpoint of `Spring Boot` application in `Playframework` application. I am accessing the `REST` endpoint using the certificate I've got. In my play application I've disabled the host name verification, but still I am getting this error. Below you can find code and configuration:

```
AsyncHttpClient-2-1, fatal error: 46: General SSLEngine problem
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found
```

**Spring Boot Application Configuration**

application.properties

```
server.port=8085
server.ssl.key-alias=demo
server.ssl.key-password=changeit
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store=server.jks
```

[image]

**Playframework Application Configuration**

application.conf

```
play.ws.ssl.loose.acceptAnyCertificate = false
play.ws.ssl.loose.disableHostnameVerification = true

play.ws.ssl {
  trustManager = {
    stores = [
      { type = "PEM", path = "public.crt" }
    ]
  }
}

play.ws.ssl.debug = {
    all = false
    ssl = true
    certpath = true
}
```

If I set `play.ws.ssl.loose.acceptAnyCertificate = true` then it is working. I want to keep it as false and then access the end point.

I feel issue is with my configuration, that's why added config only. If more information is required, I will add the code snippets too.

Comment: Do you have your Certificate for localhost?  The CN should be CN=localhost

Comment: @Grauzone No, that was the issue. It got fixed after changing CN=localhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats a keystore problem, your client is configured in a way that it checks the hostname used against metadata in the keystore. 
So you either have to set the "Subject" CN to "localhost", or add Subject Alternative Names with "localhost" in the hostname.

I like https://keystore-explorer.org/ tool for creating keystore best, adding the SAN is easy there.  Java's keytool can do the same, though with the "-ext san=dns:www.example.com"

Comment: I created new `cert` and `jks`, it got resolved. Thanks